# What is the difference between Sharepoint workflow and Event receiver?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What is the difference between Sharepoint workflow and Event receiver.

Comment: http://blog.geektrainer.com/2011/03/event-receivers-vs-workflows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SharePoint Workflow is *entirely different* from an Event Receiver. The correct choice for a solution - which may be "neither" - depends on the *specific* task at hand. Make sure to read up on the use-cases and limitations of each approach before making an initial selection.

[SharePoint Workflows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263148%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> The workflow feature in Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 enables solution architects, designers, and administrators to improve business processes. Fundamentally, *a workflow consists of two things: the forms that a workflow uses to interact with its users and the logic that defines the workflow’s behavior.* Understanding how workflows are created requires knowledge about both.

[Events / Event Receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms442323%28v=office.14%29.aspx):

> The Microsoft SharePoint [..] *events model relies on managed components called event receivers that respond to SharePoint Foundation objects when specific triggering events take place*. You create an event receiver by inheriting from one of the SharePoint event receiver base classes. After you have created the event receiver, you implement event handlers by overriding methods on the event receiver class.

See [SharePoint 2010 Development Walkthroughs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee290858%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which provides examples for both Workflows and Event Receivers.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any documents related to Workflow ?

Comment: @Ramadurai I've added a further link to walkthroughs. Other basic research questions can be addressed through searching the web.